# HTML/CSS Issues with aligning to 'inline-block' elements side by side

Tags: html, css

Please see my codepen I created at the link below.  Code is also below.

http://codepen.io/cjpicc11/pen/xRWvaR/

You will notice that block 1 and block 2 are not aligning properly to the top of the main container element and I cannot figure out why.  I was thinking setting both blocks as inline-blocks should set them to align side by side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code HTML**

```
      <div class="MainContainer">
      <div class="MainContentContainer">
        <div id="ValuesBlock">
          <h1 class="BlockHeader">
              Block 1
          </h1>
          <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3>
          <div class="Spacer">
              &nbsp;
          </div>
          <h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
          <h3>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</h3>
          <div class="Spacer">
              &nbsp;
          </div>
          <h2>Where can I get some?</h2>
          <h3>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="UpcomingEventsBlock">
          <h1 class="BlockHeader">
              Block 2
          </h1>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the </p><br>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Code CSS**

```
.MainContentContainer{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  /*background-color:#F0F0F0;*/
  background-color:#FFF;
  height:80%;
  width:80%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 45px #888888;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid 2px;
  padding:45px;
  color:#484848;
}
#ValuesBlock{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#FFF;
  margin-left:3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 45px #888888;
  width:60%;
  padding:10px;
}
h1.BlockHeader {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #103B58;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    width: initial;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    /* padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; */
    /* margin: -9px 10px 36px 1px; */
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    /* margin: -10px -5px -5px -5px; */
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 21px;
  }
  #UpcomingEventsBlock{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-left:0px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 45px #888888;
    width:30%;
    padding:10px;
  }
.footer{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Tried this? `#UpcomingEventsBlock{position:absolute;}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works:

```
vertical-align: top;
```